# Think time between Transaction Controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Transaction controller for my testing process, and I have 5 transaction controllers. Now I want to specify think time (Timer) between each Transaction controller say 300 ms.

When I add constant timer, then every sampler takes 300ms think time to process and because of this the overall response is increased a bit.

Is there any other way to give think time to only transaction controller and not individually sampler?

Answer (score 2):

You can work it around as follows:

1. Add a [Beanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the last request in each Transaction Controller
2. Put the following code into the Post Processor's "Script" area:

   ```
   Thread.sleep(300L);
   ```
3. Configure Transaction Controller to

   - generate parent sample
   - not to include duration of post processors and timers into the generated sample

See [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) guide for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I could think of 2 options that would provide required solution:

1)The easiest way would be to put the timer to the first request of the following transaction controller.
*OR*
2) At the end of the Controller add **Test Action** which can be found under Sampler where you can provide PAUSE time in milliseconds.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Test Action and select pause.  Set this to 0ms and then add a Gaussian Random timer to the test action.  Configuring timers this way will allow you to run the test with pauses or without (for debugging), test actions configured as timers will not be skipped when clicking "Start No Pauses", while the Gaussian timers attached to test actions will.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is via "Add think times to children" on the Recording controller. This will insert a "think time" action between each controller.  Then you specify the duration in ms in each Think Time action.

Usually, I would use ${thinkTime} as the duration, then specify thinkTime = 10000 or similar in the "User defined variables" config element you can add to the top of your project.

The think time is between transaction controllers, not between requests in a controller.

I am using jmeter 5.3.